# Java Stream How to skip calling a method if another method returns null

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of user id that I need to first check the database to see if an userid exists or not, if not, ignore this user id, otherwise, update this user information in the DB.  I can't change the `updateUserInDB` method, so how do I let the code skip calling the `updateUserInDB` if `checkDBforId` returns `null`?  The code below doesn't work the way I wanted.

```
 ArrayList<User> updatedUserList = userList.stream().map(user -> updateUserInDB(checkDBforId(user.getId()))
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

What I can think of is to use two streams and do `checkDBforId` and `updateUserInDB`  in two steps, but would like to know if there is a way that I can do them in one step.  Thanks.

```
  validUserList = userList.stream().map(user -> checkDBforId(user.getId()))
                                 .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());

  updatedUserList = validUserList.stream().map(user -> updateUserInDB(user))
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The User class contains `id` and `name` fields.  The methods interface:

```
  User checkDBforId(Integer userId) {

       // if userId exists in DB, return the user object from DB,
       // otherwise, return null;
   }

  User updateUserInDB(User user) {
      // update this user in the database;
  }
```

Comment: Post the signature and javadoc of both methods. Your first snippet calls updateUserInDB with one argument, and the second calls it with two. It's very confusing. Also tell us what the type of userList is. Anyway, to eliminate some eements from a stream, you use filter().

Comment: @JBNizet  Updated the post.  can I filter based on the return value of checkDBforId?

Comment: Of course you can: `filter(user -> checkDBforId(user.getId()) != null)`.

Comment: And? filter() is not map(). It doesn't transform a Stream<User> into a Stream<boolean>. It transforms a Strea<User> int a Stream<User>, by only keeping some of the users of the original streams: those that satisfy the predicate passed to filter(). Read the javadoc of filter().

Comment: @JBNizet  Thanks.  I ended up creating another method because I have some other logic in `checkDBforId`, and I now made `checkDBforId` only checks for valid user ids.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

In a single stream pipeline, as JBNIzet suggested, you can use the `checkUserInDB` to construct the `filter` predicate.

```
List<User> updatedUserList = userList.stream()
                             .filter(user -> checkDBforId(user.getId()) != null)
                             .map(user -> updateUserInDB(user))
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

On a different note, generally, databases provide a `modifyIfExists` capability, that saves you from two DB queries for such a construct. (Or even `update` operation in few of them is based on the presence of the data alongside a key.)

Comment: Thank you.  The problem is that the `checkDBforId` will return a modified user object and pass it to `updateUserInDB`.  That's why I had `updateUserInDB(checkDBforId(id))`.  The code in your post doesn't make `updateUserInDB` to take a modified user returned from `checkDBforId`, correct?